# Generic class and filtering

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a generic class:

```
public class DataProvider<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IService<T> _service;
    public DataProvider(IService<T> service) => _service = service;

    public IQueryable<T> List(params string[] includes) => _service.List(includes);
}
```

And now I would like to filter the results based on any query string parameters.
Say for example I would like to return on items that contain the word "Special" but for a particular field. Perhaps the query string would look like this:

?title=special

I would like to do something using linq to filter the results, but I am not sure it is possible.
I changed my **list** method to this:

```
public IQueryable<T> List(HttpRequestMessage request, params string[] includes)
{
    var queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
    var models = _service.List(includes);
    // TODO: Do a contains linq query
}
```

Is it possible to do a lookup like that? Or do I have to change my Generic type to an class like:

```
public class DataProvider<T> where T : Availability
{
    private readonly IService<T> _service;
    public DataProvider(IService<T> service) => _service = service;

    public IQueryable<T> List(HttpRequestMessage request, params string[] includes)
    {
        var queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        var models = _service.List(includes);
        // TODO: Do a contains linq query
    }
}
```

Even then, how do I do a lookup on the properties dynamically?
I had something like this:

```
foreach (var item in queryString)
    models = models.Where(m => m.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key).GetValue(m).ToString().Contains(item.Value));
```

Anyone got any idea how to do this?

Comment: I think you are looking for OData? https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Dynamic Linq, I was able to do this:

```
public class DataProvider<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IService<T> _service;
    public DataProvider(IService<T> service) => _service = service;

    public IQueryable<T> List(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        var queryString = request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
        var models = _service.List();
        foreach (var item in queryString)
        {
            var query = $"{ item.Key }.ToString().Contains(\"{ item.Value }\")";
            models = models.Where(query);
        }
        return models;
    }
}
```

Which solved my issue